# My 13 year old son is skipping school and I'm not sure how to proceed

Tags: behavior, teen, school, single-parent

I am a single mother, my son's father is not in the picture. My son doesn't want to go to school and is being very difficult. He says he is going, but when I get home the school tells he was not in school.

How can I help him? I am not sure how to talk to him.

Some times I get so angry at him, but I love him so much and want him to make something of himself.

Comment: Have you tried talking to him about why he doesn't want to go? And if you have, how has that gone/what has he said?

Comment: Often bullying.  Talk to his teacher and school administrators.

Comment: we'd like to help, but your question is unclear. Can you clarify what you would like help with? If you could single out one particular issue and expand on it, we might be able to give you a helpful answer. Thanks!

Comment: I hated school as well. Different reason, but the concept was the same. Have you looked into a self paced alternative? He might thrive in an environment where he can work on the whole curriculum at his own pace.

Answer (score 7):

> How can I help him?

It appears you do not know the root cause for this behavior.  You **must** figure out why this behavior is happening.  Are you taking him to school, and if so how is he being allowed to leave the school?  If not, and your able to, I would walk him into the building to make sure he actually get's in the door.

I will preface this answer as a last resort.  Try *all* other options first:

- Meet with your childs teachers
- A child psychologist
- Your childs doctor ( eliminate medical possibilities )
- Talk to your child daily
- Make sure they know you love them.

If nothing else works, I would suggest a *military school*.  At one point we had a friend whose daughter thought she would run wild over her parents (drinking, pot, sex, the works ), and they put her in military school and her attitude did a 100% about face.

The experience taught her that she is a human being, and that she should respect herself and authority figures ( parents, police, etc ).

Its a terrible position to be in, I wish you the best of luck.